# Error even though I am getting good output

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting this error. Any idea on what to do to solve for my problem. The code produces good output however I am getting this error. Full disclosure this is a homework problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nt-test-c364d945", line 3, in <module>
    assert(newton.newton(49) == 7.000000000000002)
AttributeError: module 'newton' has no attribute 'newton'
```

````
   """
File: newtons.py
Compute the square root of a number (uses function with loop).

1. The input is a number, or enter/return to halt the
   input process.

2. The outputs are the program's estimate of the square root
   using Newton's method of successive approximations, and
   Python's own estimate using math.sqrt.
"""
import math

tolerance = 0.000001
def newton(x):
   estimate = 1.0
   while True:
        estimate = ((estimate + x / estimate) / 2)
        difference = abs(x - estimate ** 2)
        if difference <= tolerance:
            break
   return estimate

def main():
   while True:
       x = input("Enter a positive number or enter/return to quit: ")
       if x == '':
           break    
       x = float(x)
       print("The program's estimate is", newton(x))
       print("Python's estimate is     ", math.sqrt(x))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()```
````

Comment: Provide relevant code section. The error is on line `assert(newton.newton(49) == 7.000000000000002)` which is not part of the code you provided.  Hint: Use `from newton import newton` if you're using it in different script then call `newton(49)== ...`

Comment: It seems you might be executing your function through some test scripts, where you are getting error due to floating point error, refer this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your traceback, you're using `newton.newton(49)` method in your script, but also you said that this newton funciton is inside `newtons` module, so looks like you need to use `newtons.newton(49)` (Don't forget to change `import newton` to `import newtons`)